# Redirect from Ajax's PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form like this:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="input" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And I have an Ajax script like this:

```
$("button").click(function(event) {
    var $ajaxData = {
        "input-val" : $("input").val();
    }

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "process.php",
        data : $ajaxData,
        dataType : "json",
        encode : true
    });
    .done(function($data) {
        alert($data["stat"]);
    });

    event.preventDefault();
    $("form").unbind();
});
```

Also a PHP script *(process.php)* where the form data is send:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['input-val'])) {
    $data['stat'] = 'success';
    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

All is correct and set, but, if I want to stop the users of seeing or going (manually) to the "process.php" page I add a redirect function:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['input-val'])) {
    $data['stat'] = 'success';
    echo json_encode($data);
}
header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

That makes Ajax's request fail automatically. **How can I stop users of going or seeing the PHP script?**
As I said, the *"event.preventDefault();"* is stopping Ajax of sending the users to the PHP script, but users can go there by themselves.

Comment: You could redirect (or just terminate the script) conditionally, only if the posted value is not present. But consider that users can post their own data to your PHP script. Also see [How to tell if a page is being called via Ajax, or on it's own](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828420/how-to-tell-if-a-page-is-being-called-via-ajax-or-on-its-own).

Comment: You could just put the header in an `else` statement: `if(isset(...)){ /*do something*/ } else { header('...'); }`

Comment: Are you missing an equal sign in your `var $ajaxData` defn?

Comment: @gibberish Yeah, it was when I was writing the question in here :|

Comment: No worries, just wanted to point it out. Hope your question is now resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, the script is expecting a JSON, while your "redirect" code sends a `HTTP 301` to a HTML file. Ultimately, the AJAX XHR is not seeing your JSON, but gets the HTML output.

Revert back your code to how it was before:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['input-val'])) {
    $data['stat'] = 'success';
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Instead, do it in the AJAX handler:

```
.done(function($data) {
    alert($data["stat"]);
    if ($data["stat"] == "success")
        location.href = 'index.php';
}) // And you are also missing a ) here.
```

According to comments:

If you are redirecting if the `$_POST` is not set, please use the `else`:

```
if (isset($_POST['input-val'])) {
    $data['stat'] = 'success';
    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Comment: They aren't trying to redirect after the ajax request but instead redirect from the php page if you didn't make an ajax request.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Ah I get that.

Comment: @ElcompJR Better create a separate page for JSON and other outputs boss.